# DELETE with ANY clause not working as expected

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, sql-delete, pgx

I'm trying to DELETE certain rows in my Postgress DB using the `ANY` clause.

Here's the structure -

```sql
---- TABLE A -----
-------------------
rId UUID NOT NULL,
oId UUID NOT NULL,
eId UUID NOT NULL,
--- <other fields>
PRIMARY KEY (rId, oId, eId),
CONSTRAINT fk_r FOREIGN KEY (rId) REFERENCES another_table(rId),
CONSTRAINT fk_eo FOREIGN KEY (oId, eId) REFERENCES some_other_table (oId, eId)
```

Suppose this table has below rows -

```
|  rId  | oId  |  eId  |
-----------------------
|   1   |  abc |  pqr  |
|   1   |  abc |  xyz  |
|   1   |  abc |  utd  |
```

I want to delete all rows from this table that have `rId = 1`, `oId = abc` AND  [`eId != pqr` AND `eid != xyz`]

I write the below query -

```sql
DELETE FROM TABLE_A
WHERE   rId = 1
    AND oId = abc
    AND eId != ANY (array['pqr'::uuid, 'xyz'::uuid]);
```

The problem is that this is not working. Both the rows that have `eId = pqr Or eId = xyz` are getting deleted. **How can I correct this?**

Passing them one by one isn't an option (I'm getting a `slice` of `eId` which I'm passing as a param to the go function that runs this query).

Something like below -

```golang
func queryToDelete(req someReq, eIds ...string) *pgx.Batch {
    batch := &pgx.Batch{}

    deleteQuery := `
        DELETE
        FROM table_a
        WHERE rId = $1
            AND oId = $2
            AND eId != ANY($3);
        `

    batch.Queue(deleteQuery, req.rId, req.oId, eIds)

    return batch
}
```

Please disregard that `1`, `abc`, `pqr` are not UUIDs in this example. I kept it that way for brevity.

Comment: `eId != [pqr OR xyz]]` -- this predicate always evaluate to true. Please elaborate.

Comment: The Impaler is correct, you should use `ALL` instead of `ANY`, e.g. `eId != ALL ($3)`.

Comment: `ALL` worked like a charm! Thanks @mkopriva and @the-impaler! Would you like to post that as an answer so that I can mark it with a tick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As The Impaler points out in their comment, `eId != ANY ($3)` will always evaluate to `true` if the `$3` array is a set with more than one element.

For your use case you should instead use [`ALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.17), e.g. `eId != ALL ($3)`.

Comment: @mkprovia - What happens when the array inside the `ALL` function is empty? Ideally, I'd want to delete all records then, but that doesn't happen.

Comment: @MananShah use an additional condition in the where clause that checks the length: `... AND (array_length($3, 1) = 0 OR eId != ALL($3))`.